# Displays binary numbers only in a Sequence

Tags: c

Write a C program that accepts an integer input n where n is the limit of the sequence (1, 2, 3, ..., n) that displays binary numbers only.

> Enter number: **15**
>
> The binary numbers will be: **0 1 10 11**

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int i, input, copy;

    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d",&input);

    printf("\nThe binary numbers will be: ");

    for (i=0; i<=input; i++) {

        if (i == 0) {
            printf("%d ", i);
            continue;
        }

        copy = i;
        while (copy > 0) {
            
            
            if (copy % 10 > 1) {
                break;
            }

            copy = copy / 10;
            if (copy == 0) {
                printf("%d ", i);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I understand the flow of the program except for this part

```
                if (copy % 10 > 1) {
                    break;
                }
    
                copy = copy / 10;
                if (copy == 0) {
                    printf("%d ", i);
                }
```

Can someone explain how this part flows? Especially, when it comes to using the modulo.

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise what you don't understand? Module operator calculates the remainder after division. For dividing by 10 the result is simply the last digit of a decimal number.

Comment: Let's say copy = 1. So It will go through first to the 1st-if which is 1 % 10 > 1 is FALSE, so it goes to second-if which is 1 / 10 is 0.1. but why will "1" be printed as an output when the condition of the second-if needs to be equals by 0?

Comment: 1/10 is 0, not 0.1

Comment: like 1 divided 10 is equals to 0? why?

Comment: Because count is an int.

Comment: OMG, thanks. I didn't realize. Thank you so much, That's why I got so confused

Comment: @Gerhardh Can I ask again? What is the purpose of "if (copy % 10 > 1) {break;}" ?

Comment: As I mentioned in first comment, `%10` calculates the last digit. If the last digit is larger than 1 it dos not mach your requirement

Comment: Like if copy is 2, then 2 % 10 = .2? Am I right?

Comment: And why is there "while (copy > 0)"?

Comment: No, `2%10` is no `.2` but it is `2`. Executing that instruction and printing the result should show this immediately. And I strongly suggest to run your program in a debugger. Step through each instruction, watch closeley where your execution flow is going along and check content of variables. For a start you can also use pen&paper to step through your program.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understand it! Bless your soul :'>

Answer (score 0):

The code you added doesn't makes much sense to me but i can see you are trying to test each bit but in a wrong way, the goto method would use the bit-wise and operador `&` and the shift operador `<<`; olso you need to take in account the endianness.

```
true = 0000 0111 & 0000 0010
false = 0000 0111 & 0100 0000

0000 1000 = 0000 0100 << 1
0011 1000 = 0001 1100 << 1
0000 1000 = 0010 0000 >> 2
```

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    char buff[17];
    buff[16] = '\0';  // marks the end for printf

    unsigned base, num, bit;
    for (int c = 1; c < argc; c++){
        num = strtol(argv[c], NULL, 10);
        bit = 16;
        base = 1;
        while (0 < bit--){
            if (num & base){
                buff[bit] = '1'; 
            } else {
                buff[bit] = '0';
            }
            base <<= 1;
        }
        printf("'%u' -> %s \n", num, &buff);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Use it with `.\ints_to_bin.exe 6 9`:

```
'6' -> 0000000000000110
'9' -> 0000000000001001
```